# Fancybox dynamic width/height issue - how to code in the defaults to fall back on?

Tags: jquery, fancybox, fancybox-2

I am just trying to implement this:

http://jsfiddle.net/BJNYr/

```
$(".fancybox")
.attr('rel', 'gallery')
.fancybox({
    type: 'iframe',
    autoSize : false,
    beforeLoad : function() {                    
        this.width = parseInt(this.href.match(/width=[0-9]+/i)[0].replace('width=',''));  
        this.height = parseInt(this.href.match(/height=[0-9]+/i)[0].replace('height=',''));
    }
});
```

But I am wondering what do I have to add to the fancybox declaration so that it has default width/height to fall back on, in case the user doesn't pass width/height in the URL like in the example above (people forget or mess up the spelling or something)... just thinking how do I prevent issues like that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `fitToView` along with `minWidth`, `minHeight`, `maxWidth` and `maxHeight` to set you fallback size like :

```
$(".fancybox")
.attr('rel', 'gallery')
.fancybox({
    type: 'iframe',
    autoSize : false,
    beforeLoad : function() {                    
        this.width = parseInt(this.href.match(/width=[0-9]+/i)[0].replace('width=',''));  
        this.height = parseInt(this.href.match(/height=[0-9]+/i)[0].replace('height=',''));
    },
    // fallback size
    fitToView: false, // set the specific size without scaling to the view port
    minWidth : 200, // or whatever, default is 100
    minHeight: 300, // default 100
    maxWidth : 800, // default 9999
    maxHeight: 900  // default 9999
});
```

On the other hand, to avoid the issues of people messing up with the url, you could use (HTML5) `data-*` attributes to pass those values like :

```
<a class="fancybox" href="http://fiddle.jshell.net/YtwCt/show/" data-width="500" data-height="200">Open 500x200</a>
```

...which is cleaner. Then in your fancybox set the size accordingly within the callback like

```
beforeShow: function () {
    this.width = $(this.element).data("width") ? $(this.element).data("width") : null;
    this.height = $(this.element).data("height") ? $(this.element).data("height") : null;
}
```

Check this **[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/HfpGe/)**, the firs link has `data-*` attributes and gets the size accordingly. The second doesn't so gets the size according to the fallback values

Comment: And I used this jsfiddle code instead of the one you suggested as the admin of the site preferred passing width/height in the URL like that instead of data-width and data-height.

Comment: the problem with your method `this.width = parseInt(this.href.match(/width=[0-9]+/i)[0].replace('width=',''));` is that it fails if not parameters are passed. You need to evaluate first if they exist

Comment: gotcha! I added ... if(this.href.indexOf("width") >= 0){... condition to mine then and that should work now. Thanks for the heads up!