# Fancybox iframe different sizes for different viewports

Tags: jquery, html, css, media-queries, fancybox-2

I want to have 2 types of fancy box iframe size for mobiles version width: 95%, height: 85% for pc version - width: 85%, height: 80% How can I set these 2 versions up?

Comment: What have you tried? Have you tried using media queries in your css? you tagged it here so you must know what they are. Did that not work? Share code that shows you made an effort and you'll get more help here.

Comment: Sorry. I'm a total newbie at this. How and where would you declare the appropriate media query. Within the fancybox.css or in my own custom css file.

Comment: doesn't matter as long as it's in the css. http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_mediaquery.asp

Comment: Ok Gregg, I will try that. Thanks.

Comment: check http://stackoverflow.com/a/17507964/1055987 to get the idea. no need to use media queries